# iOS 9 - Web Form Not Submitting When Photo Selected from Existing Library

Tags: html, ios, forms, file-upload, image-uploading

I am creating a form in a web app that needs to upload an image file.

This should work whether you take a "new photo" or choose a file from your "existing library".

I am testing the form on iOS 9.1 and I can get it half-working.

If I take a NEW photo, then it works perfectly and advances to the success screen.

If I choose a photo from my existing library, then it does not work. It sort of appears like it's working, but then it just reloads the same page. The data never submits to the backend.

I'm using code I used with iOS 8 and if I recall, it worked properly.

This is what I have:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="defaultForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="/receipt-submit" enctype='multipart/form-data'>

  <div class="form-group receiptContainer">
    <div class='upload-photo' onclick="$('#receipt').click()">
      <image src='/img/camera-icon.png' class='img-responsive' alt='' />Upload Your Receipt</div>

    <div id="Ugly">
      <input type="file" name="receipt" id="receipt" accept='image/*' />
    </div>

  </div>


  <button type='submit' name="validateBtn" class="upload-photo submit" id="validateBtn">Submit</button>

</form>
```

I had to get fancy with the styling, which is why you see that div with an id = "ugly".

I would love to get this working with button new and existing images, but nothing I try seems to work.

Any help or ideas is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue which has plagued my users since IOS 9 came out. I FINALLY fixed it. Basically, the issue is that Safari Mobile drops the .jpg from the uploaded filename for .jpg media files.  Screenshots and current Camera are .pngs, and they get uploaded with an extension, so they work.  It's just images you take with the camera and save to the media roll ahead of time that don't have an extension at upload time.  Since most server side back end systems check extensions to determine whether the file is an image and should be post-processed, it's most likely that on the server side you are receiving the file, but you are instantly discarding it because it has no extension.  Since I couldn't test with a true IOS device against my local dev environment, and ergo, step through the server side code after being submitted by an actual IOS Device (not an emulator), I assumed the same thing, that the input was never getting posted.